# What is the difference between NVL() & COALESCE() function in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Wanted more clarity on these differences with some practical examples.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us some sample data, and the results.

Comment: `COALESCE()` is ANSI SQL, and expected to be portable!

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between both if only 2 arguments are passed in `COALESCE`.

`NVL` can take only 2 arguments while `COALESCE` can take as many arguments as you want (There must be some limit but that I will update soon)